# How can I escape $ so I can hyperlink to it in R Markdown?

Tags: r-markdown, dollar-sign

I used $ as a name for one of my sections. I then noticed that the hyperlink from my table of contents to that section does not work. Can this be fixed? I've tried escaping it with \ and I've even tried `$`, but neither changed the outcome.

This is my header

```
output:
  github_document:
    toc: true
```

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced your problem in this code example with R Studio Version 4.1.

It seems to be a github_document thing, because it works when you knit to output: html_document.

A possible solution is to add a [backslash-escaped space](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#backslash-escapes) ( `# $ \`  )behind the dollar and it is parsed as a nonbreaking space.

````
---
title: "Repro Example Dollar Sign in title"
output:
  github_document:
    toc: TRUE
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


Some Example content to test whether shortcut works

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

Some Example content to test whether shortcut works

# Header One (normal text)

Some Example content to test whether shortcut works



# $


If $ is without text it doesn't work

Some Example content to test whether shortcut works

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

Some Example content to test whether shortcut works

# $ \

Add a backslash-escaped space behind the dollar and it is parsed as a nonbreaking space.

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## $ Header 2 with dollar and text in title (shortcut works)

Some Example content to test whether shortcut works

# header 3

Some Example content to test whether shortcut works

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

Some Example content to test whether shortcut works
````

Versions that I tested which don't work:

- using inline r code to print the dollar sign with two trailing spaces `` # `r stringr::str_pad("$",  width = 3, side = "right")` ``
- `# $••` (double space)
- generating the $ from a chunk: ```` ```{r results='asis'}  cat("#", " $", "  ") ``` ````

[image: Rstudio Example]

Comment: This doesn't work. If you put more content in the example above, your output will then be big enough for you to notice that clicking on `$` in the table of contents does not move the screen.

Comment: I don't think that Stack Overflow has parsed what you've typed correctly. A section named by "pound space dollar-sign space backslash" still doesn't work.

Comment: there needs to be a space behind the backslash, that way the space gets escaped

Comment: Thanks, but that still doesn't work on my machine even after copy and pasting what you've put. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape `\`,`^`,`$`,`.`,`?`,`*`,`|`,`+`,`(`,`)`,`[`, and `{` with backslashes.

Comment: No luck. That gets me a section called "\$" that doesn't hyperlink.

Comment: Try more backslashes?

Comment: \\\\$ was no better.